# Find sum of expressions $x_1\dotsb x_k$ where summation is over solutions for $n=x_1+\dots+x_k$

Tags: summation, generating-functions

Let's define $f(n,k)$ as sum of expressions of $x_1 x_2 \dotsb x_k$ where summation is performed over all positive solutions for $n=x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k$ and i'm interested in closed form of $f(n,k)$

My idea was as follows: Let's design straightforward reccurence pattern
$$f(n,k) = \sum_{i=1}^n i \times f(n-i,k-1) + [n=0 \wedge k=0]$$

if we say that $\mathcal{E}_k(x)$ is generating function for $f(n,k)$ (fixing $k$ here) then
$$\mathcal{E}_{k}(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \times \mathcal{E}_{k-1}(x) + 1$$
So it's convolution of $\langle i \rangle _ {i=1}^\infty$ and $\langle f(i,k-1) \rangle _{i=0}^\infty$ plus one.
But i can't really move forward from there. Are generating functions good tools for this task? I'd appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Does the order of $x_i$ matter? I mean if $n=3$ and $k=2$ then $f(n,k)=2$ or $f(n,k)=4$?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann yes, order of $x_i$ matters.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann and possible solutions for $n=3 \wedge k=2$ are $1+2$ and $2+1$ and $3+0$ and $0+3$ but we don't really care about solutions that contain 0's in them.

Comment: you were talking about positive solutions, did you mean non-negative?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann yeah i still mean non-negative solutions, but it really doesn't matter, cause $3 \times 0 = 0 = 0 \times 3$

Comment: all in all, I think that recursive formula is not correct, because you do not "mention" that you care about the order of $x_i$ in the formula

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43313/discussion-between-michael-freimann-and-spinach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can represent $n=x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k$ where $x_i$ is group of $x_i$ ones then the answer if number of such solutions with exactly one element picked out from each of $k$ groups. So the solution is little variation of stars and bars and the answer is $$\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}$$